# Event Polling in real time

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

```
document.body.onclick = function(e) {
    e = e || event
var target = e.target || e.srcElement
// variable target has your clicked element
    innerId = target.id;
    //  do your stuff here.
    isClicked = 1;


}

document.body.onmousemove = function()
{

hasMouseMoved = 1;
//console.log(hasMouseMoved);
}
window.onresize = function()
{
  isresized =1;
  //console.log(isresized);
}

window.onscroll = scroll;

function scroll()
{
   alert("scroll event detected! " + window.pageXOffset + " " + window.pageYOffset);
   isScrolled=1;
   //console.log(isScrolled);

}
document.body.onkeypress = function(evt)
{
  evt = evt || window.event;

    if (evt.keyCode!=='undefined') {
        // Do your stuff here
        isPressed = 1;
       // console.log(isPressed);
    }
return isPressed;
}

  function getResult() {
      result =  ***hasMouseMoved+"|"+isClicked +"|"+isPressed+"|"+isresized+"|"+isScrolled+***"|";
      //console.log(result);
      return result;
    }
  //  return result;
//}
var final = getResult();
  console.log(final);
```

So I have these 5 event handlers which manipulate/handle user interaction with both the keyboard and the mouse. I have a function `getResult` which gets the changes in the flags associated with each of these functions. When I run this Javascript with an HTML page, I need to constantly type `getResults();` in console to get changes in those flags after I have typed/mousepressed/mousemoved/scrolled/resized. I want the changes to show up in real time with those flags changing with interactions.

Please help me understand how to poll these handlers so as to give the result in real time. As of now the flags (`isPressed`/`isScrolled`/`isResized`/`hasMouseMoved`/`isClick`) are assigned 0 and remain so in `getResults` function call with final variable. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call getResult() at the end of each handler function:

```
console.log(getResult());
```